# Bigquery: how to select multiple matching records from a column

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to write a query to fetch the matching records from a column. The table 'abc' has this column 'category'.

```
mango
mango,orange
mango,orange,banana
pineapple
guava
grapes
guava,blueberry
.
.
.
```

The desired result is this:

```
mango
mango,orange
mango,orange,banana
guava
guava,blueberry
.
.
.
.
```

My code is like this:

```
Select * 
From abc
Where column_name like '%mango%' 
      and column name like '%guava%'
```

Category column has thousands of rows and I can not hard-code each of them. Is there any way I can get the desired output? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you clarify on why you want to filter by 'mango' and 'guava' but not by 'grapes'? What is the rule to pick the fruit that you want to filter by?

Comment: Also, your query do not return the result you posted. Your query look for strings that contains "mango" and "guava". I guess you wanted to use "OR" instead of "AND" between the 2 clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below options

```
select * 
from your_table 
where exists   (
    select * from unnest(split(fruits)) fruit 
    where fruit in ('mango', 'guava')
  )
```

or

```
select distinct t.* 
from your_table t,  unnest(split(fruits)) fruit 
where fruit in ('mango', 'guava')
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]